# how to get the anniversary per year based on date field

Tags: formula

I need to create a formula field that will give the anniversary (based on hire date ) of an employee per year. How can i achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to calculate anniversary based on date . So it is like calculating age using date

```
IF( NOT( ISBLANK( Birthdate ) ) ,
  IF( DATE( 2000 , MONTH( Birthdate ) , DAY( Birthdate ) ) <= DATE( 2000 , MONTH( TODAY() ) , DAY( TODAY() ) ),
     YEAR (Today()) - YEAR ( Birthdate ),
     YEAR (Today()) - YEAR ( Birthdate ) -1 ),
  null)
```

use this formula and instead of birth date use your hire date field.

[Reference:](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-calculate-the-age-for-a-Contact&language=en_US)